# ActiveMQ multiple topics using CMS

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

I am trying to create multiple topics within same connection by creating separate session for each topic. both Topics and 1st durable consumer created successfully but I am getting error while creating 2nd consumer. Code work perfect with single topic but I need to create multiple topics in run time within same connection

Following is the code

```
    activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::initializeLibrary();

    // create connection factory    
    auto_ptr<ConnectionFactory> connectionFactory(ConnectionFactory::createCMSConnectionFactory(brokerURI));

    // create a connection
    connection = connectionFactory->createConnection(uname,pwd,applicationId);  

    connection->setExceptionListener(this);
    // adding transport listener
    ActiveMQConnection* amqConnection = dynamic_cast<ActiveMQConnection*>( connection );
    amqConnection->addTransportListener( this );

    // create a session
    session[0] = connection->createSession( Session::AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE );
    session[1] = connection->createSession( Session::AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE );


    destination[0] = session[0]->createTopic(serviceTopic);
    topic[0] = session[0]->createTopic(serviceTopic);

    destination[1] = session[1]->createTopic(serviceTopic2);
    topic[1] = session[1]->createTopic(serviceTopic2);

    producer[0] = session[0]->createProducer(destination[0]);
    producer[1] = session[1]->createProducer(destination[1]);


    consumerDurable[1] = session[1]->createDurableConsumer(topic[1], applicationId, getSelector(0), false);
    consumerDurable[1]->setMessageListener(this);

    consumerDurable[0] = session[0]->createDurableConsumer(topic[0], applicationId, getSelector(1), false);
    consumerDurable[0]->setMessageListener(this);
```

------------ Variable values --------------

applicationId = "Test123"

getSelector(0) = "CID NOT LIKE 'Test123' AND Durability LIKE '0'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html) help page on ActiveMQ. It explains how durable subscriptions work against a topic. In particular this:

> JMS specification dictates that the identification of S is done by a
>   combination of the clientID and the durable subscriber name. This is
>   so that the JMS connection S uses can have many different durable
>   subscriptions on different topics or on the same topic with different
>   selectors - yet the JMS provider can know which message for which
>   subscription to keep around for it.

You need to use different IDs for different consumers.